# Erro de ao fazer comando aggregate com $geoNear do MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

Eu possuo uma `collection` chamada `location` com os seguintes dados:

```
{
    _id: ObjectId("5a900f4af1b7fd855010c0cf"),
    car_id: ObjectId("5a85c26a35fdcf1098c23480"),
    location: {
        type:"Point",
        coordinates:[-54.585186,-25.447471]
    }
}
```

E estou tentando fazer um comando `aggregate` no `mongoshell` da seguinte forma:

```
db.location.aggregate([{
  $geoNear: {
    near: { type: "Point", coordinates: [ -73.99279 , 40.719296 ] },
    distanceField: "dist.calculated",
    includeLocs: "dist.location",
    spherical: true,
    maxDistance: 10000
  }
}])
```

Mas sempre recebo esta mensagem de erro:

```
assert: command failed: {
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "geoNear command failed: { ok: 0.0, errmsg: \"error processing query: ns=taxxer.location limit=100Tree: GEONEAR  field=location.location.coordinates maxdist=10000 isNearSphere=1\nSort: {}\nProj: { $...\", code: 2, codeName: \"BadValue\" }",
        "code" : 16604,
        "codeName" : "Location16604"
} : aggregate failed
```

Não consigo descobrir o que estou fazendo de errado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi o problema ao trocar o nome da minha `collection` onde estão as `location` para outro.

Aparentemente a `collection` não pode ter o mesmo nome do atributo, como no erro:

```
field=location.location.coordinates
```

Ao trocar o nome para outra coisa, por exemplo, `carlocation`, o comando já funciona.